# How to select the required div id, if there are duplicates in the div id?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I've got into an issue by using the div id tag (duplication?). Am using the reference path instead of absolute path in order to avoid some issue however, now my selenium stopped identifying the count.

The reference path I use:

```
//*[@id="mx_objectCount"]
```

The Source code occurrences:

```
<div id="mx_objectCount" class="object-count"></div>

<div id="mx_objectCount">26 objects</div>
```

All I am interested is the total count. How do I skip the first and jump to the next one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select only the second `div`, you can make use of the missing `@class` attribute of the second `div` like this:

```
//*[@id="mx_objectCount" and not(@class)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in multiple ways.

Get first node based on class name and jump on following siblings.

```
//div[@class=‘object-count’]/following-sibling::div
```

Get second node though based common attribute like Id. (not recommended as index can be changed)

```
(//div[@id=‘mx_objectCount’])[2]
```

OR

```
(//div[@id=‘mx_objectCount’])[last()]
```

Using text if ‘objects’ will not be changed

```
//div[contains(text(), ‘objects’)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Xpath** its easy to capture elements, if there are duplicate or already existing Id, name, className etc.

Using **ChroPath**(for google chrome browsers)and **Fire path**(for Firefox browsers) you can easily get the Xpath.